# XmlDocument saving the file incompletely

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xmldocument

I have a simple code which modifies an existing XML file as follows:

```
roomsfile = new File(Path.Combine(rootDir, "rooms.dat"));    
XmlDocument roomdata = new XmlDocument();
roomdata.Load(roomsfile.AbsolutePath);
XmlElement root = roomdata.DocumentElement;
XmlNode roomNode = roomdata.CreateElement("room");
XmlNode noNode = roomdata.CreateElement("no");
XmlNode nameNode = roomdata.CreateElement("name");

//roomNo and roomName are text fields
noNode.InnerText = roomNo.Text; 
nameNode.InnerText = roomName.Text;

roomNode.AppendChild(noNode);
roomNode.AppendChild(nameNode);
root.AppendChild(roomNode);

roomdata.Save(roomsdat.AbsolutePath);
```

My original XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rooms>
  <room>
    <no>101</no>
    <name>Reception</name>
  </room>
  <room>
    <no>102</no>
    <name>Manager Room</name>
  </room>
</rooms>
```

When I run the code it turns the file into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rooms>
  <room>
    <no>101</no>
    <name>Reception</name>
  </room>
  <room>
    <no>102</no>
    <name>Manager Room</name>
  </room>
  <room> 
    <
```

So it's clearly incomplete. And then it broke my app when I try to use the file. What would cause this kind of behaviour?

For the record, this application is being written on Xamarin (MonoDroid) in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a short but complete console app just using normal .NET? (I'd strongly advise using LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument, but only because it's a clear API - your code should work...)

Comment: I don't find wrong with the code, and xml are same except the '<' in last line. Also I would rather suggest to use Linq to Xml, as I don't think using XmlNode.InnerText  is a good idea.

Comment: Which File class do you use for `new File()`? It looks strange.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have much time really. Also I'm not good in LINQ, always using code pieces, never wrote a LINQ code from scratch.

Comment: @RohitPrakash Yes, it is incomplete as you see. I also tried creating XmlText's instead of using InnerText.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is "Java.IO.File". Like I said, this is a Xamarin Android application.

Comment: Now I tried to save into another file than original one. And guess what, it worked that way. Now I could just delete the original and rename the new. But this is really a bad practice. I need to know the cause.

Comment: Could be the file write method is being interupted. Maybe by the application going to sleep or something. Ive seen that sometimes on .Net

Comment: Learning LINQ to XML (and LINQ - they're different things) will *save* you huge amounts of time. Next: how did you view the incomplete file? Did something else possibly still have the file open?

Comment: @EmreCanSerteli - writing to a new file, then deleting the old and renaming the new, is actually good practice.  That way, if anything happens while writing the file (e.g. the disk fills up, or the user kills your process) then the original file is untouched.

Comment: On Windows Desktop the only problem I see is your line `roomsfile = new File(...));` - `File` is a [static class](http://docs.go-mono.com/).  Perhaps you meant `new Uri(Path.Combine(rootDir, "rooms.dat"))`?  Otherwise your code works on Windows Desktop assuming `rooms.dat` already exists.  Perhaps the Monodroid version of XmlDocument.Save() has a bug when overwriting a pre-existing file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that it's just the way my XML file appears while the app's still using it. Even if I copy the file to my PC and view it with Notepad++, it still seems broken. But the app uses it just as expected, without any problems (it was apparently another issue that broke it before). A weird behaviour, if you ask me. But I won't dig it any further.

Anyway, in the comments, dbc pointed out a simple but cool tip about overwriting files, which I believe is crucial in preventing potential corrupt file issues in any app. I'll use this as a rule of thumb for the rest of my coding life:

> Writing to a new file, then deleting the old and renaming the new, is actually good practice. That way, if anything happens while writing the file (e.g. the disk fills up, or the user kills your process) then the original file is untouched.